# Java MVC: Keeping my view updated

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to practice my MVC layouts. One area I'm struggling with is keeping my view updated during a long process.

I have a program that does some scraping on my site. It returns the data to a table in my Swing based GUI. It's working at the moment where my program runs, and at the end of the run it finally updates the table.

In my model I am storing my results in some form of collection, probably an ArrayList. This is constantly being updated while the long process is running. I need a way of updating my view based on the information in my Arraylist results in the model.

I'm not sure what methods I can use to do this. I was thinking of somehow putting a method in my controller that would constantly check the results arraylist while the long process is running and update the view. Or should I have some way of checking when the model changes?

I don't really know what direction I need to go in to implement this and I'm just looking for some pointers.

This is my controller at the moment, if you need anything more just let me know.

```
public class BrowseController {
private BrowseModel m_model;
private BrowseView m_view;

public BrowseController(BrowseModel model, BrowseView view) {
    m_model = model;
    m_view = view;

    view.addRunListener(new RunListener());
    view.addClearListener(new ClearListener());
}

class RunListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        m_view.setStatus("running");
        HashSet<String> urls = m_view.getTargetUrls();

        for (String url : urls){
            m_model.processUrl(url);

            m_view.setResult(m_model.getResults());
        }

    }
}

class ClearListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("clear");
        m_view.reset();
        m_model.reset();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get notified whenever you list is updated, you can use an [ObservableCollection](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/events/apidocs/org/apache/commons/events/observable/ObservableCollection.html). It will trigger an event whenever your list is modified.

Also I'm not sure if you are using the model correctly. Is `m_model.processUrl(url);` a Setter? If not you should move the logic from that method into the controller. The model should only store the data with minimal (or no) logic.